# How do I remove an OS from a partition?

Tags: partition

I just bought an SSD drive and installed Linux Mint in it. My question is: how do I *remove the OS in the old drive* safely without deleting my home directory from the old drive?

My first thought were:

1. Remove the partition from Grub (Grub file is in new drive)
2. Remove all partitions but my /home directory

Are they enough and safely? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why not just save the data in your home directory elsewhere and then format the old drive for use as storage?

Comment: You will have to add more information regarding your partition setup. Your solution sounds fine as long as home is a separate partition. You should however first delete the old OS partition(s) and then simply run `update-grub`. Just use e.g. `cfdisk`. Make sure your PC really boots from the new drive in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @NasirRiley: That's a very good solution, the problem is former /home directory has 500GB in it, and I cannot find space for that size in another partitions.

Comment: Do you have or can you purchase an external hard drive? You can copy the data to it, format the drive, and then put it back when it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with your assessment,
removing the partition from grub and removing all BUT your /home from that partition should be enough to get rid of your old OS.
You should however, make sure that no symlinks in your home directory point to files that would be deleted. The find-solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522051/how-to-list-all-symbolic-links-in-a-directory) should list all your symlinks in order for you to review them.

Aside from that, I would recommend @nasir-riley's approach of just copying your home to a different place e.g. your new system partition. That way you could prevent the old partition from being mounted and could therefore test your "new" home without the danger of loosing data.